# Spring ManyToOne - OneToMany Lazy loading not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I am working for a while on an application based on Spring Boot 2.1.6, Hibernate, MySql, JavaFX, Envers and Java 8 - no Web - which helps a product owner to administrate requirements and alike. When the application starts I only want to load all product entities in order for the product owner to select which product he/she wants to work on. To make sure that the other related entities are not pulled from the database I tried to implement lazy loading. Unfortunately my lazy loading annotation doesn't prevent the loading of the entire database. Unlike most examples that I found, I am using a tree structure, that is, the parent and the children are of the same abstract class Term.

It all starts with

```
@Controller
public class LoginPaneCtrl {

    @Autowired TermService termService; 

    public void initialize() {
        ...
        List<Product> productList = termService.getAllProducts();
        ...
     }

     // rest of class omitted
}
```

the service class looks like this

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TermService {

    @Autowired  private ProductRepository productRepository;


    public ObservableList<Product> getAllProducts() {
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        products.addAll(productRepository.findAll());

        return products;
    }

    // rest of class omitted
}
```

The repository is very simple

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ProductRepository extends TermRepository<Product> {
// empty interface
}
```

and

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TermRepository<T extends Term> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    List<T> findByIdentifier(String indentifier);
    List<T> findByGoal(String goal);
    List<Product> findByParent(Term parent);
    List<T> findAll();
}
```

The product class itself holds several references to other entities. Due to the use of JavaFX all my entity classes have to be AccessType.PROPERTY. For brevity I omit most of them but keep representative fields..

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Term.PRODUCT)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)    // JPA reading and writing attributes through their getter and setter methods
@Audited
public class Product extends Term {

   protected StringProperty classification;
   protected ObjectProperty<Employee> projectManager;
   protected List<Persona> personas;    // which type of users will use this product
   protected List<Double> marketGrowth;

    @ElementCollection  
    public List<Double> getMarketGrowth() {
        return marketGrowth;
    }


    public void setMarketGrowth(List<Double> marketGrowth) {
        this.marketGrowth = FXCollections.observableArrayList(marketGrowth);
    }

    public String getClassification() {
        return classification.get();
    }

    public void setClassification(String classification) {
        this.classification.set(classification);
    }

    public StringProperty classificationProperty() {
        return classification;
    }

    // Unidirectional. The Employee is not aware of this reference
    public Employee getProjectManager() {
        return projectManager.get();
    }


    public void setProjectManager(Employee productOwner) {
        this.projectManager.set(productOwner);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Employee> projectManagerProperty() {
        return projectManager;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)      // Unidirectional mapping
    public List<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return personas;
    }

    public void setPersonas(List<Persona> aPersonaList) {
        this.personas = FXCollections.observableList(aPersonaList);
    }

    public void addPersona(Persona aPersona) {
        if(! personas.contains(aPersona)) {
            personas.add(aPersona);
        }
    }

    public boolean deletePersona(Persona aPersona) {
        return personas.remove(aPersona);   
    }
}
```

The superclass Term looks like this - for brevity I omit most fields but keep those where I belief the issue is caused..

```
@Entity
@Access (AccessType.PROPERTY)    // JPA reading and writing attributes through their getter and setter methods
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn (          // In concrete classes @DiscriminatorValue("here the class id")
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
        name = "term_level",
        length=10
        )
@Audited
public abstract class Term  implements Serializable { 

    private Long id;    

    /*
     * A Term may be broken down into sub-Terms, called children. A child can not be a Term from a higher hierarchical level.
     * Between parent and child is a bi-directional relationship
     */
    protected ObjectProperty<Term> parent;
    protected List<Term> children;
    protected ObjectProperty<Term> predecessor;
    protected ObjectProperty<Term> successor;

    protected List<UserRequirement> requirements;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "termGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="termGenerator", sequenceName = "term_Seq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public Term getParent() {
        return parent.get();
    }

    public void setParent(Term aParent) {
        this.parent.set(aParent);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Term> parentProperty() {
        return parent;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Term> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    @PostLoad
    /** 
     * Sorting  Terms is difficult due to overlapping release and commercialization trains running in parallel. 
     * Hence plannedBegin and predecessor/successor information must be evaluated to build a correct order
     */
    protected void sortChildren() {

        if(children.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        ObservableList<Term >aChildrenList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Step 1: Filter all terms with no predecessor and order by plannedBegin
        ArrayList<Term> heads = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Term child: children) {
            if(child.getPredecessor() == null) {
                heads.add(child);
            } 
        }
        Comparator<Term> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Term::getPlannedBegin);
        Collections.sort(heads, comparator);

        // Step 2: Move the other elements to their position depending on successor/predeccessor information
        Term successor = null;
        for(Term head: heads) {
            aChildrenList.add(head);
            do {
                successor = head.getSuccessor();
                if(successor != null) {
                    int pos = aChildrenList.indexOf(head);
                    aChildrenList.add(pos+1, successor);
                    head = successor;
                }
            } while(successor != null);
        }

        children = aChildrenList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")     // Used by JPA
    // The list will be sorted after the entity is set using @PostLoad 
    protected void setChildren(List<Term> aChildrenList) {
        children = aChildrenList;
    }
}
```

Looking at the below SQL trace, after the expected SQL select statement, all Term children are queried (classical n+1 problem since lazy loading is not working) and thereafter it queries user requirements, their persona, next test plans and test cases, and so on. As far as I can say, lazy loading works nowhere in my entire class model and the entire database is loaded, although I only need the Product entities.

```
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        Product as generatedAlias0 */ select
            product0_.id as id2_59_,
            product0_.goal as goal3_59_,
            product0_.identifier as identifi4_59_,
            product0_.level as level5_59_,
            product0_.parent_id as parent_25_59_,
            product0_.plannedBegin as plannedB6_59_,
            product0_.plannedEnd as plannedE7_59_,
            product0_.predecessor_id as predece26_59_,
            product0_.state as state8_59_,
            product0_.successor_id as success27_59_,
            product0_.fk_testplan as fk_test28_59_,
            product0_.timeUnit as timeUnit9_59_,
            product0_.type as type10_59_,
            product0_.version as version11_59_,
            product0_.affection as affecti12_59_,
            product0_.classification as classif13_59_,
            product0_.classificationDirective as classif14_59_,
            product0_.intendedUse as intende15_59_,
            product0_.negativeImpact as negativ16_59_,
            product0_.productLine_id as product29_59_,
            product0_.productOwner as product17_59_,
            product0_.projectManager as project18_59_,
            product0_.purpose as purpose19_59_,
            product0_.restriction as restric20_59_,
            product0_.systemDescription as systemD21_59_,
            product0_.systemEngineer as systemE22_59_,
            product0_.technologyReadinessLevel as technol23_59_,
            product0_.unlike as unlike24_59_ 
        from
            Term product0_ 
        where
            product0_.term_level='Product'
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([goal3_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [first product] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Product] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([parent_25_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_] : [DATE]) - [2019-09-22] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_] : [DATE]) - [2030-11-23] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([predece26_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([success27_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [62] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_] : [INTEGER]) - [42] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([affecti12_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([classif13_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([classif14_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([intende15_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([negativ16_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([product29_59_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([product17_59_] : [VARBINARY]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([project18_59_] : [VARBINARY]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([purpose19_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([restric20_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([systemD21_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([systemE22_59_] : [VARBINARY]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([technol23_59_] : [INTEGER]) - [0] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([unlike24_59_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.planning.Term.children#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.planning.Term.requirements#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.portfolio.Product.environmentalInterfaces#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.portfolio.Product.marketGrowth#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.portfolio.Product.marketSize#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.portfolio.Product.marketUnits#1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.CollectionType.getCollection:813: Created collection wrapper: [com.agiletunes.shared.domain.portfolio.Product.personas#1] 
Hibernate: 
    select
        marketgrow0_.Product_id as Product_1_29_0_,
        marketgrow0_.marketGrowth as marketGr2_29_0_ 
    from
        Product_marketGrowth marketgrow0_ 
    where
        marketgrow0_.Product_id=?
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:65: binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1] 
Hibernate: 
    select
        marketsize0_.Product_id as Product_1_31_0_,
        marketsize0_.marketSize as marketSi2_31_0_ 
    from
        Product_marketSize marketsize0_ 
    where
        marketsize0_.Product_id=?
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:65: binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1] 
Hibernate: 
    select
        marketunit0_.Product_id as Product_1_33_0_,
        marketunit0_.marketUnits as marketUn2_33_0_ 
    from
        Product_marketUnits marketunit0_ 
    where
        marketunit0_.Product_id=?
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:65: binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1] 
Hibernate: 
    select
        children0_.parent_id as parent_25_59_0_,
        children0_.id as id2_59_0_,
        children0_.id as id2_59_1_,
        children0_.goal as goal3_59_1_,
        children0_.identifier as identifi4_59_1_,
        children0_.level as level5_59_1_,
        children0_.parent_id as parent_25_59_1_,
        children0_.plannedBegin as plannedB6_59_1_,
        children0_.plannedEnd as plannedE7_59_1_,
        children0_.predecessor_id as predece26_59_1_,
        children0_.state as state8_59_1_,
        children0_.successor_id as success27_59_1_,
        children0_.fk_testplan as fk_test28_59_1_,
        children0_.timeUnit as timeUnit9_59_1_,
        children0_.type as type10_59_1_,
        children0_.version as version11_59_1_,
        children0_.affection as affecti12_59_1_,
        children0_.classification as classif13_59_1_,
        children0_.classificationDirective as classif14_59_1_,
        children0_.intendedUse as intende15_59_1_,
        children0_.negativeImpact as negativ16_59_1_,
        children0_.productLine_id as product29_59_1_,
        children0_.productOwner as product17_59_1_,
        children0_.projectManager as project18_59_1_,
        children0_.purpose as purpose19_59_1_,
        children0_.restriction as restric20_59_1_,
        children0_.systemDescription as systemD21_59_1_,
        children0_.systemEngineer as systemE22_59_1_,
        children0_.technologyReadinessLevel as technol23_59_1_,
        children0_.unlike as unlike24_59_1_,
        children0_.term_level as term_lev1_59_1_ 
    from
        Term children0_ 
    where
        children0_.parent_id=?
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:65: binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [8] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([term_lev1_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([goal3_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Product sale and normal maintenance support] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Commercialization] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2022-04-25] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2027-04-22] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([predece26_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [10] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([success27_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [9] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [8] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [9] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([term_lev1_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([goal3_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Discontinue maintenance support. End of sale] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Decommision] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2027-04-23] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2028-04-22] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([predece26_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [8] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([success27_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [9] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [10] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([term_lev1_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Release] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([goal3_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [first release] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Release] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2019-09-22] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2022-04-22] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([predece26_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([success27_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [8] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [63] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [0] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [10] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [17] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([term_lev1_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([goal3_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Product sale and normal maintenance support] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Commercialization] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2024-11-25] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2029-11-23] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([predece26_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [19] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([success27_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [18] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [17] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([id2_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [18] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([term_lev1_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([goal3_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Discontinue maintenance support. End of sale] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([identifi4_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Decommision] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([level5_59_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Phase] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([parent_25_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedB6_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2029-11-26] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([plannedE7_59_1_] : [DATE]) - [2030-11-23] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([predece26_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [17] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([success27_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:51: extracted value ([fk_test28_59_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [null] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value ([version11_59_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1] 
TRACE 14:07 o.h.t.d.s.BasicExtractor.extract:61: extracted value 
 ...
```

This continues for 275 thousand (!) lines of SQL, querying I belief the entire database.

I know that I can solve the current issue with a DTO, but it not solve the issue at the many other use cases, since something is generally wrong.

Therefore, please find also my application.properties

```
#No JMX needed - disabling it allows for faster startup
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.main.banner-mode=off
#no web server needed
spring.main.web-application-type=none

# Properties can be queried in the code e.g. @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")   private String message;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/agiletunesdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&characterSetResults=utf-8
spring.datasource.username=YYYY
spring.datasource.password=XXXX

# create db schema
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#----  Naming strategy: Use underscore instead of camel case
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#----  Prevent LazyInitializationException
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

#----  Prevent use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator] table-based id generator
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#----   Show sql queries send to db
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
#----   Print SQL statements spread over multiple lines for easier readibility
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I have a number of suspicions, but have no evidence. Maybe lazy loading doesn't work on Repositories that inherit from a @NoRepositoryBean? Maybe it is that parent and children cannot be derived from the same superclass? And I understand that lazy loading is a kind of "recommendation" but how can I influence this decision? I assume there no randomizer making the decision ;-)

Comment: You have a PostLoad annotated methods that iterates through all the children and thus loads the collection, which thus causes the loading of all the children, and thus the call to their own PostLoad-annotated method, etc. etc.

Comment: Good catch JB. Without the sorting the SQL reduced significantly. Thank you! But still the User-Requiremnt and the Personas are queried once - no more n+1. But the it becomes weird: The Product is updated - although I don't see a difference - but the version increments. Then the references to the Persona are deleted and then immediately inserted one after the other. How can that be?

Comment: The original question is answered. If you have a new question please ask a separate question. 

It would also be nice if @JBNizet or you could post the answer as an answer and accept it, so others see that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see JB Nizet comment- I moved the @PostLoad into the controller.